# How to edit a property on 'window', 'document'(width,height) from QtWebKit?

Tags: qt, webkit

I tried to change like that(worked on the 'navigator' object)

```
page->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript(
    "var navigator=new Object;"
    "navigator.someProperty=...");
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case, I would use the signal [javaScriptWindowObjectCleared](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qwebframe.html#javaScriptWindowObjectCleared)

That kicks in just before load, when the window has been cleared.

You probably want to validate the origin before doing anything, though.

That being said - and I am not too sure what you want to achieve - I wouldn't manipulate the javascript scope like that. Maintaining and deploying javascript is easier than doing the same for C++. So, I would instead just expose a simple C++ object to the javascript scope (via [addToJavaScriptWindowObject](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qwebframe.html#addToJavaScriptWindowObject)), and then have the javascript code test this object and do what it has to do.

Either way, hope this helps.

Comment: And I would like to stress that "after page's downloading and before javascript execution" is a contradiction. Now, using javaScriptWindowObjectCleared, you can indeed inject your script before anything starts, and wait for any proper javascript event that you would deem appropriate (DOMContentReady... whatever).